# findstr: [^inverse class] incorrect behaviour

Tags: findstr

I don't want findstr to display a string that contains 'btq' between - and -

For example: ghjgvyu-btq-jklli8j

So I've tried this command:

```
echo ghjgvyu-btq-jklli8j|findstr .*-[^btq]-.*
```

Not working at all... Does not display anything with or without ^

Then I tried:

```
echo ghjgvyu-btq-jklli8j|findstr "[^btq]"
```

Does the opposite: It always displays the string no matter if ^ is used.

It's only working correctly when I echo btq and nothing else:

```
echo btq|findstr "[^btq]"
```

But that's not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be to run `findstr` with `/V`, `/C` and `/R` parameter:

```
findstr /V /R /C:"-btq-"
```

`/R` is a parameter which enables searching with a regex. With parameter `/C` you specify a concrete string/regex which you are searching for in a line and with `/V` you search for lines which do not contain the match given in parameter `/C`.

So for example:

```
@echo off

echo 1 ghjgvyu-btq-jklli8j | findstr /V /R /C:"-btq-"
echo 2 ghjgvyu-bt-jklli8j | findstr /V /R /C:"-btq-"
echo 3 ghjgvyu-b-jklli8j | findstr /V /R /C:"-btq-"
echo 4 ghjgvyu-avc-jklli8j | findstr /V /R /C:"-btq-"
echo 5 abc | findstr /V /R /C:"-btq-"
```

gives me

```
2 ghjgvyu-bt-jklli8j
3 ghjgvyu-b-jklli8j
4 ghjgvyu-avc-jklli8j
5 abc
```

You see, the string `ghjgvyu-btq-jklli8j` which should not occur in the output does not occur there.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem is that /V can't be used for searching inside a file with other strings if you still want findstr to find a specific string. I should have mentioned this in my startpost. I have a file like this:

    jjhjg
    kjljlkl
    lkjkjjjjjjj
    ghjgvyu-btq-jklli8j
    cv
    ghjgvyu-cfg-jklli8j
    kjjjjjio
    ghjgvyu-avc-jklli8j

Now I want findstr to only display all strings that contain ghjgvyu*jklli8j but not display ones that contain -btq- (ghjgvyu-btq-jklli8j)
It can be done with piping to another findstr command be would prefer 1 findstr command.